# Round button CSS3 hover not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've found a great hover effect for my buttons which I would like to incorporate in my website. However, it's not working. It's htis snippet: http://cssdeck.com/labs/fhxam1sb

Now I have the following code, which only gives me a black square with no hover effect at all. What am I missing?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <title>Animated Buttons with CSS3</title>

<style media="screen" type="text/css">
// Basic Round Button Layout
a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 40px;
}
.effect-1 {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 100px;
  @include border-radius(50%);
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-family: 'Monoton', cursive;
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);

  &:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    @include transition(background-color 0.2s);

    &:after {
      @include scale(1);
      @include transition(transform 0.2s);
    }
  }
}

.effect-1:after {
  position: absolute;
  top:-10px;
  left: -10px;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  @include border-radius(50%);
  @include box-shadow(0 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.8));
  @include scale(0.7);
  @include transition(transform 0.2s);
}


</style>


</head>
<body>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<a href="#" class="btn effect-1">M</a>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The CSS you've posted is actually SASS - thus the `@include` statements that won't be parsed properly unless you have SASS installed and running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the wrench icon on the left hand side in cssdeck: You'll see that it's using SCSS w/ Compass rather than vanilla CSS. In order to use it in your site, you'll need to compile it to CSS.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try to find how to do that!